# Wordpress: Changing a posts category after a comment is posted

Tags: wordpress, tags, comments, categories

There is plenty of info out there on changing post categories, just nothing relating specifically to changing post categories after a comment is made.

I'd like to have a section of my site showing only posts with comments.

I've tried adding this code I found on this website for changing tags, in about a dozen different places

```
<?php wp_set_object_terms( '<?php the_ID(); ?>', 'new', 'category', 'true' ); ?>
```

I've tried using it in

```
<?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've tried using wp_insert_comment and comment_post hooks with other codes around the internet, with no success.

I guess the same thing could be achieved with adding tags to posts after a comment is made but I've no idea where to start there.

Have any of the experts on here ever seen a wordpress blog with a seperate area only showing posts with comments?  I'm no coder, I might be attempting the impossible without even being aware of it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: This might help - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38753/how-to-get-comments-by-post-id

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `comment_post` action hook. This function can't take post ID or $post object as parameters, so you have to add `global $post;` to get access to it.
From `wp-includes/comment.php`:

```
do_action('comment_post', $comment_ID, $commentdata['comment_approved']);
```

**Example usage**

```
//in functions.php
    add_action( 'comment_post', 'so_custom_comment_post' );
    function so_custom_comment_post(){
      global $post;
      //Be sure the term 'new' is already available
      wp_set_object_terms( $post->ID, 'new', 'category', true );
    }
```

Hope it helps! Let me know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array('post_type' => 'post');
$post_obj = new WP_Query($args);
while($post_obj->have_posts() ) : $post_obj->the_post();
    //display posts with comments
    $comments = get_comments(array(
        'post_id' => $post->ID));
    foreach($comments as $comment) { 
        echo '<li>'.the_permalink().'</li>';
    }
 endwhile;
 ?>
```

Comment: Hi, I'll give it a go just now.

Comment: So it is possible to get a list of posts with comments, thank you!

Comment: Posts with multiple comments are obviously showing more than once on the list, which makes this unworkable but its a good starting point for me.  Adding tags/categories to posts would be idea but this is a good starting poin for another route.